# Azure function stops putting messages in storage queue

Tags: azure-functions, azure-queues

I have an Azure (let's call it **A**) function that have to put thousands of messages in an Azure storage queue. A uses a for loop to put the messages into the queue. Every message is an object serialized in JSON (it's very small).

This queue is used to trigger another Azure function. Let's call it **B**. Only 4 instances of B can start at the same time.

I'm **not** using a consumption plan.

It happens that at some point A stops putting messages in the queue and i can't figure out the reason.

From the Azure function console i don't get any error message. No exceptions arise. It simply stops.

For example it should put 30000 messages but during the tests it managed to put between 180 and 1600 messages.

Any piece of advice would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `Always On` enabled?

Comment: Yes i do. The function B is configured to be instantiated 4 times.

Comment: Could you share the code of your functions?

Comment: You have a limit of maximum outbound tcp connections in Azure Function Apps. So please check that you do not exceed the limits while running your loop.